# Listen for exit of another application

Tags: c#, .net, events

Is it possible to get notified when a specific Windows application(s) is terminated/closed when using C# and .Net? It could be any application, that is listen in the Windows job list.

Comment: You can *periodically* check processes using [Process.GetProcesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses(v=vs.110).aspx) and see if your process is still in the list.

Comment: I just took a look at Process and there seams to be an event for this callsed: Process.Exited Event. I will try with that one.

Comment: Consider wiring up a TaskCompletionSource to that event

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `WaitForExit` method like this:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById(process_id);

process.WaitForExit();
```

This will cause the executing thread to wait until the process has exited.

If you don't want to block the thread, and instead receive a notification when the process has exited, you can use the following:

```
public static void NotifyOnProcessExits(Process process, Action action)
{
    Task.Run(() => process.WaitForExit()).ContinueWith(t => action());
}
```

And use it like this:

```
NotifyOnProcessExits(process, () => Console.WriteLine("Process has exited"));
```

Please note that this solution will keep one thread-pool thread waiting for the process to exit. You might be able to find a better solution that is truly asynchronous, I am not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using System.Diagnostics . I have written a program before that would kill double instances of an application. I don't think there are events you can wire up to monitor when a specific program has been closed but you can check periodically if the program still exists on the list of processes and trigger an even when it is not found.

```
   if(!Process.GetProcesses().Any(p => p.ProccessId == Id)); { //or Process Name
      //Your logic here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could register the process and then get notified via an event using

```
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject
```

This will allow your application that is currently doing the monitoring to run as expected, without being blocked.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject(v=vs.110).aspx).